# Mysql sys_exec Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 11, wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to use sys_exec to run native command on unix, but I've tried to put the plugin from https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys

Into the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin#` but when I try to run this command below:

`create function sys_exec returns int soname 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';`

I am receiving this response:

`ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 11, wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)`

It is MariaDB 15.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to fix that:

First of all we need to install `default-libmysqlclient-dev` on unix

Run the command: `apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev`

Then download the repository from: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys

After the download completed we can run this command:

`gcc -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -fPIC -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o lib_mysqludf_sys.so`

Then copy `lib_mysqludf_sys.so` to the MariaDB/MySQL plugins folder, how to know which is the folder?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'plugin_dir';
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                       |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
| plugin_dir    | /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/ |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In my case my command should be:

`cp lib_mysqludf_sys.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/`

After that, we can create our trigger and run everything that we need to run on our own OS :D

```
CREATE TABLE `trig_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `random_data` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER trig_test 
AFTER INSERT ON `trig_test`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
 DECLARE result int;
 SET cmd=CONCAT('node /tmp/script/script.js >> /tmp/script/result.txt');
 SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO trig_test
(random_data)
VALUES('GOOOO!!!');
```

If you can't run the commands you need to check the permissions, I changed my owner and group from /tmp to tests

`chown -R mysql.mysql /tmp`

Then everything works!!!

Comment: Will you share you 64-bit lib_mysqludf_sys.so? Thanks

Comment: This plugin can run even in a x86 or 64 bits, because our servers are all 64 bits, and worked, try this and let me know if it is right, otherwise we can handle this issue together!! :)

Comment: I did but I still error. I am using Centos 7 x64 with `15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB`

Comment: You way works, but seems impossible to pass a variable from trigger to cmd, see details at Github [link](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/issues/31)