# Running python script from MySql trigger with sys_exec() gives exit code 1

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I have a MySql server locally (on Windows 10) and want to run a python script from a trigger. For taht, i want to use sys_exec().
I got the lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll  from here: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/data/exploits/mysql

and set the UDF up as described here: https://osandamalith.com/2018/02/11/mysql-udf-exploitation/

sys_exec is working:

```
mysql> SELECT sys_exec('python --version')//
+------------------------------+
| sys_exec('python --version') |
+------------------------------+
|                            0 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.52 sec)
```

but when i want to run the script:

```
mysql> SELECT sys_exec('python C:\dbtest.py test')//
+--------------------------------------+
| sys_exec('python C:\dbtest.py test') |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    2 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

As far as i understand, the 2 indicates, that the file was not found.
How can i fix this?

When i use '\\', the exit code changes to 1 (Invalid_Function ?):

```
mysql> SELECT sys_exec('python C:\\dbtest.py test')//
+---------------------------------------+
| sys_exec('python C:\\dbtest.py test') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.57 sec)
```

Comment: MySQL [knows nothing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=201&p=1&q=sys_exec) about sys_exec().

Comment: i honestly don't know what i'm supposed to do with this comment ???

Comment: You must describe completely where this (user-defined) function is taken from.

Comment: SELECT sys_exec('python --version') returns -1 for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was with the access permissions of the mysql user. I wasn't able to find out wich (windows) user actually runs the python script and needs access to the used files, but the way i solved the problem was to grant "everyone" access to the files involved.

Answer (score 0):

the MySQL UDF SYS is not installed.

Here you can find the Answer to do that : [Mysql sys_exec Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 11, wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241615/mysql-sys-exec-cant-open-shared-library-lib-mysqludf-sys-so-errno-11-wrong)

here also the git for download: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys

Comment: No. The mysqludf_sys is installed, the udf sys_exec is created and works.